# ASP.NET Multiple Submits with Same Name with Masterpage

Tags: asp.net, webforms, attributes, postback

I'm using a master page with multiple submit buttons to sort a table, as well as other submits on the page doing other things. I'd like to name all the submits for sorting the table the same name (sortTable), so I can do something like this on PostBack to pass the value of the column to sort by:

```
if (Request.Form["sortTable"] != null)
{
    sortTableBy(Request.Form["sortTable"]);
}
```

My problem is that when I run the site all the names are replaced with different values like `ctl00$mainContent$ctl01` making it hard to capture them by a single name on postback. Any advice?

Comment: Don't use `Request.Form`, but handle the buttons Click events properly.

Comment: Mind pointing me toward what "properly" means?

Comment: The `OnClick` or `OnCommand` event of a Button Control. Or RowCommand if the Button is in a Repeater, GridView etc.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

VDWWD's comment put me on the right track to solve this problem. I just added a function for each of those submits to call onclick and then put my sort table code in there. Thanks VDWWD.